# How to use OptionT when one of my expressions returns a Future[Seq[User]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am trying to use optionT, where my functions are returning `Future[Option[T]]`

One of my calls returns a `Future[Seq[T]]`, how should I handle this case?

```
for {
  user <- OptionT(api.getUser(123))
  company <- OptionT(api.getCompany(user.companyId))
  employees <- api.getEmployees(company.id) // returns Future[Seq[Employee]]
} yield CompanyProfile(user, company, employees)
```

**Update**
I also have a method that returns a Set[Int].  Not sure how to wrap that into a OptionT, I tried:

`.liftM[OptionT]` but that didn't work.

Comment: What I usually do is turn the options into lists with `toList` not sure there is a `toSeq`.

Answer (score 1):

```
employees <- OptionT(api.getEmployees(company.id).map(Option(_)))
```

Comment: what about a method that returns a Set[Int].  Do I need to wrap it with a future and liftM[OptionT] ?  I tried that but didnt' work.

Comment: No need to lift it into `OptionT` in that case, you can write `result = <method returning Set[Int]>` in the for-comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example for what you are asking, including the update to the question (a method that returns `Seq[Employee]`, outside the `Future` context):

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.implicits._

case class Employee(x : String)
case class User(x : String)
case class Company(x : String)
case class CompanyProfile(user : User, company: Company, employees: Seq[Employee])

def emptyEmployees : Future[Seq[Employee]] = Future.successful(Seq())
def nonEmptyEmployees : Future[Seq[Employee]] = Future.successful(Seq(Employee("Test1"),Employee("Test2")))
def user : Future[Option[User]] = Future.successful(Some(User("user1")))
def company : Future[Option[Company]] = Future.successful(Some(Company("company1")))

val res: OptionT[Future, CompanyProfile] = for{
  user <- OptionT(user)
  company <- OptionT(company)
  employeesOne <-  OptionT(nonEmptyEmployees.map(Option(_))) // Here you wrap the `Seq[Employee]` into an `Option`
  employeesTwo <- OptionT.pure[Future, Seq[Employee]](employees) // Here you lift the `Seq[Employee]` into the context of `OptionT[Future, Seq[Employee]]`
} yield CompanyProfile(user, company, employeesOne ++ employeesTwo)

Await.result(res.value, Duration.Inf) 
   // Option[CompanyProfile] = Some(CompanyProfile(User(user1),Company(company1),List(Employee(Test1), Employee(Test2), Employee(Test3), Employee(Test4))))
```

However note that, as @Zhang Liu mentioned in the comments to his answer, you don't **have to** add it to the `OptionT` context. You would probably call that method from within the `yield` block.

**Update**
A bit unrelated to your question, but useful to remember as it helps testing scenarios like yours, you can also abstract the `Future` away, so it is easier to test your code without worrying about `ExecutionContexts` etc.

My previous code would then become:

```
def emptyEmployeesM[M[_]](implicit m : Monad[M]) : M[Seq[Employee]] =
  m.pure(Seq.empty)

def nonEmptyEmployeesM[M[_]](implicit m : Monad[M]) : M[Seq[Employee]] =
  m.pure(Seq(Employee("Test1"),Employee("Test2")))

def employees : Seq[Employee] = Seq(Employee("Test3"),Employee("Test4"))

def userM[M[_]](implicit m : Monad[M]) : M[Option[User]] = m.pure(Some(User("user1")))
def companyM[M[_]](implicit m : Monad[M]) : M[Option[Company]] = m.pure(Some(Company("company1")))

def companyProfile[M[_]](implicit m : Monad[M]): OptionT[M, CompanyProfile] = for{
  user <- OptionT(userM[M])
  company <- OptionT(companyM[M])
  employeesOne <-  OptionT(Functor[M].map(nonEmptyEmployeesM[M])(Option(_)))
  employeesTwo <- OptionT.pure[M, Seq[Employee]](employees)
} yield CompanyProfile(user, company, employeesOne ++ employeesTwo)

// Here we still use Future
val res1 = Await.result(companyProfile[Future].value, Duration.Inf) // Option[CompanyProfile] = Some(CompanyProfile(User(user1),Company(company1),List(Employee(Test1), Employee(Test2), Employee(Test3), Employee(Test4))))

// However here we can use another Monad, in this case Id (which is simply a type alias to itself), which allows to test more easily your companyProfile method.
val res2 = companyProfile[Id].value // Option[CompanyProfile] = Some(CompanyProfile(User(user1),Company(company1),List(Employee(Test1), Employee(Test2), Employee(Test3), Employee(Test4))))
```